# Get mac id of pc or laptop who Altered your db. SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alter-table, spid

Is it possible to get the MAC ID of the PC/Laptop that was used to do some malicious operations on a SQL Server database.

I used this SQL command:

```
DECLARE @current VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @start VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @indx INT;

SELECT @current = path
FROM sys.traces
WHERE is_default = 1;

SET @current = REVERSE(@current)

SELECT @indx = PATINDEX('%\%', @current)

SET @current = REVERSE(@current)

SET @start = LEFT(@current, LEN(@current) - @indx) + '\log.trc';

-- CHNAGE FILER AS NEEDED
SELECT 
    CASE EventClass
       WHEN 47 THEN 'Object:Deleted'
       WHEN 164 THEN 'Object:Altered'
    END, *
FROM::fn_trace_gettable(@start, DEFAULT)
WHERE 
    EventClass IN (47, 164) 
    AND EventSubclass = 0 
    AND DatabaseID <> 2
ORDER BY 
    StartTime DESC
```

This able to give a lot of information regarding the operation. One of them was the Hostname, Likewise would it be possible to get the MAC ID of the said Hostname.

I read somewhere That I can only get the MAC ID If he PC is using the same LAN.
But That is not the case here. I Tried the below code too.

```
use master

select 
    hostname, 
    MAC = substring(net_address, 1, 2) + '-' +
          substring(net_address, 3, 2) + '-' +
          substring(net_address, 5, 2) + '-' +
          substring(net_address, 7, 2) + '-' + 
          substring(net_address, 9, 2) + '- ' +
          substring(net_address, 11, 2)
from 
    sysprocesses
where 
    spid in ('51','55','64','58','60','65','73','79','80','81','83')
```

Here the spid I got the the Previous command. But that is not unique to that particular "Hostname"/PC. So I only got the servers macid. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT hostname,net_address FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE net_address<>''
```